# Aurelia : Refresh view with a Map value

Tags: javascript, aurelia

In the viewModel I have a Map which is refreshed every 5s :

```
 Constructor(){
        this myMap=new Map();

    }
    activate(){
       //for example :
       value=7;
       id=1;
       setInterval(()=>{
          this.myMap.set(id, value++);
          });
        },5000);
    }
```

In the view :

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
  <h2>${titre}</h2>
  <p class="nb-values-OK">
    ${myMap.get(1)}
  </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Nothing happen when interval triggers ... Is there any way to have my view refreshed when the timer triggers ?

In fact in the real world, I have lanes and on these lanes there are some activities ; so my map do the link between a lane id and the number of activities which take place on that lane. It appears to me that a Map is the simplest way to sort this ...
Anyway, my first question concerns the way to have my view refreshed every 5sec.

Thanks in advance for any help.
`

(Hope my english is good enough to be understandable :)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need use `bind(this)` in callback-functions for access inner model data like `this.myMap`:

```
Constructor(){
    this myMap=new Map();
}

activate(){
    //for example :
    value=7;
    id=1;
    setInterval(function(){
        this.myMap.set(id, value++);
    }.bind(this), 5000);
}
```

If you need to observ and update complex data then you can use [many bindable behaviors](https://www.danyow.net/aurelia-binding-behaviors/). Most simple solution -- using of signal api (view bindable value will be updated every time then you send special signal):

**model.js**:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';

@inject(BindingSignaler)
export class SampleView {

  constructor(signaler) {
    this.signaler = signaler;
  }

  activate() {
    this.data = new Map();
    this.data.set(1, 1);

    // data changing by interval and send update signal
    setInterval(function(){
      this.data.set(1, this.data.get(1) + 1);
      this.signaler.signal('need-update');
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  }
}
```

**model.html**

```
<template>
  <h1>${data.get(1) & signal:'need-update'}</h1>
</template>
```

P.S.

Also for custom property or expression observer you can use BindingEngine (create events on your map value change). See example in that topic: [Property change subscription with Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419242/property-change-subscription-with-aurelia/28437456#28437456)

Also you can try expressionObserver from BindingEngine (to observe array or "inner" object values): https://stackoverflow.com/a/33482172/1276632

Comment: Thanks, to be frank I've seen this link [binding-behavior](https://www.danyow.net/aurelia-binding-behaviors/), but I didn't catch the thing :( Your example clarified it :) and now it works.